# How to find the password of a WiFi network?

Tags: 8.0, settings, wifi

My phone (a Nokia Lumia 520) is connected to a WiFI network but I've forgotten the password. Is there any way I can get the password of the wifi network that I am currently connected to?

Answer (score 7):

You can't. For the security purposes.

Answer (score 7):

> Note: The below instructions apply to Windows Phone 8.1. If your phone has not already received this update from your carrier or OEM, you may want to consider signing up for and installing [Preview for Developers](http://www.wpcentral.com/how-sign-windows-phone-81-preview-developers).

If you have a Windows 8 computer, and log in to it with the same Microsoft account you use for your phone, the WiFi profiles can be synced to the computer. From there, you should be able to view the password just as you can with any other remembered network on the PC.

WiFi profiles are synced by default, but [here's how you can verify or toggle the setting on your phone](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/how-to/wp8/settings-and-personalization/sync-my-windows-phone-settings).

> 1. In the App list, tap Settings Settings icon > Sync my settings.
> 2. Turn on syncing for the settings you want synced between this phone and your other Windows devices.

Here's [how to verify and change the sync setting on your Windows 8 PC](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/sync-settings-pcs).

> 1. Swipe in from the right edge of the screen, tap Settings, and then tap Change PC settings. (If you're using a mouse, point to the lower-right corner of the screen, move the mouse pointer up, click Settings, and then click Change PC settings.)
> 2. Tap or click OneDrive, and then tap or click Sync settings.
> 3. Under the different settings categories, turn off the settings you no longer want to sync. [Or turn/leave on the ones you do want to sync.]

Finally, [how to get the WiFi passwords on your Windows 8 PC](http://www.microsoft.com/surface/en-us/support/networking-and-connectivity/how-to-find-your-wireless-network-password). Note that this requires the PC to be in range of the wireless network.

> **Windows 8.1: Find your password**
>
> Step 1:   Swipe in from the right edge of the screen, and tap Settings. (If you're using a mouse, point to the lower-right corner of the screen, move the mouse pointer up, and
> then click Settings.)
>
> Step 2:   Tap or click the network icon for the network you want to connect to, and then tap or click Connect.
>
> Step 3:   Swipe in from the right edge of the screen,
> and tap or click Search.
>
> Step 4:   In the search box, enter view network connections, and in the search results tap or click View network connections.
>
> Step 5:   In the Network Connections window, press and hold or right-click the network name, and then tap or click Status.
>
> Step 6:   Tap or click the Wireless Properties button.
>
> Step 7:   Tap or click the Security tab, and tap or click the Show characters check box.
>
> Step 8:   The password for the wireless network is displayed in the Network security key field.
>
> **Windows 8: Find your password**
>
> Step 1:   From the Start screen, swipe in from the right edge of the screen, and then tap Settings. (If you're using a mouse, point to the upper-right corner of the screen, move the mouse pointer down, and then click Settings.)
>
> Step 2:   Tap or click the wireless network icon.
>
> Step 3:   Tap and hold or right click on a wireless network name, and then choose View connection properties.
>
> Step 4:   Select Show characters to see the wireless network password.

If your PC isn't in range of the wireless network, you can use tools like NirSoft's [WirelessKeyView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/wireless_key.html) to get the password.

Answer (score 6):

### Privacy concerns.

These settings are controlled by OS and not exposed to apps. So, there is no other way to get to it.

Only one way i can suggest is, login to the router config page and check its Wireless password, but for that you should know router credentials.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open browser in your mobile.
2. Enter your router setting ip (available in router manual, if you
   have dlink then use 192.168.0.1).
3. Enter valid password(if you dont know this password then use
   default password, available in router manual).
4. Open setup tab where your old password is available. Just tick show
   password if password is hidden.